# Only one identity column per table is allowed

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, code-first, fluent

I have this class :

```
public  class Comment
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public DateTime AddDate { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PostId")]
    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsApproved { get; set; }
    public virtual int LikeCount { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Comment Parent { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Comment> Children { get; set; }
    public virtual Member Member { get; set; }
    public virtual byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}
```

and I use fluent API like this:

```
this.HasRequired(x => x.Post)
    .WithMany(x => x.Comments)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete();

this.HasOptional(x => x.Parent)
    .WithMany(x=>x.Children)
    .HasForeignKey(x=>x.ParentId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

When I want to run the project, I get this error:

> Multiple identity columns specified for table 'Comments'. Only one
>   identity column per table is allowed. Visual Studio 2013

I just have one primary key in this class and that is `Id` in first line.

Anyone? I need help

Comment: Where is the error that you are getting?

Comment: @Joker I add Error to Post .

Comment: Do you have any fluent API configurations?

Comment: @NikolayKostov I add my flue API . please see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you most probably have more than one key defined. The one that is defined in your model is `Id` and the other is defined in your fluent API.

I've tried to reproduce your problem and the code worked perfectly.

Here are my models:

```
public class Comment
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public DateTime AddDate { get; set; }
    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsApproved { get; set; }
    public virtual int LikeCount { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Comment Parent { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Comment> Children { get; set; }
    public virtual Member Member { get; set; }
    public virtual byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
public class Member
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the code I've used to check if the models are working properly:

```
var db = new ApplicationDbContext();
db.Comments.Add(new Comment()
    {
        AddDate = DateTime.Now,
        Body = "asd",
        IsApproved = true,
        LikeCount = 12,
        Member = new Member(),
        Post = new Post()
    });
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes EF is unable to correctly order the methods in the DbMigration class.  This might happen when you have renamed the PK of some of your entities then add a migration and try to update the database. In order to make it work, go to your migration class (the one that inherits from DbMigration and is auto-generated when you add a new migration)  and in the Up() method make all the drop statements precede all other statements.

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        DropForeignKey();
        DropForeignKey();
        DropIndex();
        DropPrimaryKey();
        RenameColumn();
        RenameColumn();
        RenameIndex();
        RenameIndex();
        AddForeignKey();
        AddForeignKey();
        AddPrimaryKey();
    }
```

If the AddPrimaryKey() statement for a table precedes the DropPrimaryKey() statement you will add a primary key before removing the other one and thus you will temporary have two primary keys for that table, and a primary key is an identity column. Therefore you get the "Multiple identity columns specified for table" exception.